# Make a new calendar with Google api in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way to make a new calendar with the Google calendar api?
And is there a way to make calendars not linked to a google account?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) for this purpose. It has a good example with [Google Calendar events](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.6.1/demos/gcal.html). If you don't need a link to google account, you could use [basic view](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.6.1/demos/basic-views.html) of the calendar.

I am using this calendar and pretty happy with customization that it provides.

BTW: Backend technologies aren't important for this task as for me.